# hrule in footer, alignment

Tags: header-footer, context

This is probably some basic stuff, but I can't find the proper way to align a simple `\hrule` on the right side of the page, above the page number.

```
\starttext

\setuppagenumbering[location={footer,right}]

\setupfooter[text][before=\hrule height .03in width 1.5in]

\setupfooter[strut=yes,style=bold]

\input ward

\stoptext
```

[image: simple example]

Comment: Please provide a complete MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) that we can compile that shows your problem.

Comment: @PeterWilson: That is a complete MWE for ConTeXt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to place a rule above the pagenumber is to disable the automatic placement and use `\setupfootertexts` to put the pagenumber in the footer.

```
\setuppagenumbering
  [location=]

\startsetups [pagenumber]
    \framed
        [
            width=1.5in,
            align=flushright,
            frame=off,
            topframe=on,
            foregroundstyle=bold,
        ]
        {
            \prefixedpagenumber
        }
\stopsetups

\setupfootertexts
  [] [\directsetup{pagenumber}]

\starttext
\input ward
\stoptext
```